# Yii Php : Using CdbCriteria for finding records with primary keys

Tags: php, sql, yii, primary-key, criteria

i'm using **Yii php**, and having trouble with finding records with an array of primary keys.

I know that:

```
$idArray = array(1,2,3);
$model = SomeModel::model()->findAllByPk($idArray);
```

above code works. But i want to know how to do it in **CdbCriteria** for I still have other conditions to add, that i cant do in the typical find() methods.

**How do i search records with primary keys in CdbCriteria?**

--------------Edited---------------------------

I need to create a CActiveDataProvider using the model I retrieved.

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($model,array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,

        ));
```

sadly above doesn't work. Below works.

```
return new CActiveDataProvider('SomeModel',array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,

        ));
```

Comment: Do You want all records with above given Id`s?

Comment: yes. I basically have an array of id's (primary keys) but I need to do it in CdbCriteria way because i still have some conditions. I only want to retrieve the records given the pks

Comment: ok, Is this array of ID`s fixed? means fixed size or variable?

Comment: fixed size.. i already know them before hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array
 $idArray = array(1,2,3);
You can write like this.

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Mymodel',array(
             'criteria'=>array(
        'condition'=>'id IN ('$idArray[0].',' .$idArray[1].','.$idArray[2].')',
        'order'=>'id DESC',
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$idArray = array(1,2,3);

$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "CONDITION_HERE";

$model = SomeModel::model()->findAllByPk($idArray , $criteria);
```

Comment: please see edited post. I need the criteria because i need to create a CActiveDataProvider with it